# How to undo e.g. a move operation in Thunar on Debian?

Tags: debian, thunar

Currently I fail to find whether it's possible to undo an operation in Thunar on Debian.  For example, if I move a file using Thunar, how may I then undo this? I tried using right click on the file system or by opening the edit menu, but I can't find an "undo" option. Also <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> does not seem to work (nothing happens).

Answer (score 1):

You can't undo in Thunar (see [comment 9](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14259#c9), specifically). You can use something like Dolphin instead, which is [more powerful](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/dolphin/dolphin/quick-tips.html#undo-actions).